# How to justify 4 divs in one row

Tags: html, css, layout

I have HTML/CSS layout problem:

I have 4 divs  with the same width and height. I want to "justify them" so thay should be place from one side to the other with the same spaces between them. In other word: suppose the A, B, C, D are divs and "|" means start/end of row. So I want receive following effect of 3 divs in one row:

```
|A    B    C    D|
```

How to do it. I was able to do it with 3 divs, but how to do it with 4 divs?

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried please?

Comment: is the row wide enough ? if you could do it with 3 and it's not working with 4 then that suggests not. don't make total width 25% , unless you're using border-box, as they will drop down

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For full browser support, you can use the below:

```css
#container {
    text-align: justify;
    -ms-text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
    text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
    width:100%;
}
#container>div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
    background:red;
}
span {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div> <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: This is best - it works on safari 7:).

Comment: Only Internet Explorer supports the text-justify attribute

Answer (score 6):

Using flexible boxes:

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please do jsFiddle for it.

Comment: See the code snippet.

Comment: @P.K. why? The snippet shows exactly what a fiddle would

Comment: Click "Show code snippet"

Comment: This one is not working on Safari 7:(

Comment: It works on Safari with code: display: flex;
  display: -webkit-box;      /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */  
  display: -ms-flexbox;      /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
  display: -webkit-flex;
  justify-content: space-between;

Answer (score 2):

Live example is here:  http://jsfiddle.net/gLxr3cqk/1/

```css
#container {
  text-align: justify;
}
#container > div {
  width: 100px; /* Declare your value. Can be in relative units. */
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 1px black solid;

  /* IE fix. */
  *display: inline;
  zoom: 1;
}
#container:after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```